# Inverse tensor with indices

Tags: tensor

I'm trying to write an inverse tensor with mixed indices, meaning I want both a `{-1}` and a `{\lambda}` in the superscript - but ideally not at the same level/size, since they are different notations. Double superscripts aren't allowed, so I tried writing

```
\tensor{\Lambda^{-1}}{^\lambda_\mu}
```

using the `tensor` package, but this wasn't allowed either. Any suggestions for how to get round this?

Comment: What exactly keeps you from doing `\tensor{\Lambda^{-1^{\lambda_\mu}}}` (untested)?

Comment: It shows:

Error: Sub/Superscript items out of order...

I don't know how to get around double superscripts not being allowed.

Comment: Sounds like a problem due to tensor. If you could post a complete, minimal example, we might be able to help more. Otherwise try the superscript outside of tensor, `\tensor{\Lambda}^{-1^{\lambda_mu}}`. The usual math mode can handle multiple superscripts.

Answer (score 2):

Just brace the first main argument:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

$\tensor{{\Lambda^{-1}}}{^\lambda_\mu}$

\end{document}
```

[image]