# Nice looking double superscript

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, superscripts

How can I make a nice look double superscript like the picture which was made in MS Word?

```
{R}^e{^{\mathbf{Tx}}}
```

[image: double superscript]

Comment: You really would need to define "nice" from your point of view, or - better even - give an example why you don't like the default LaTeX method `R^{e^{\mathbf{Tx}}}`.
Also: Maybe related to [Inverse tensor with indices](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/358749/100384)

Comment: One `{` is misplaced. I would also replace `\mathbf` with `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath`. Try `R^{e^{\boldsymbol{Tx}}}`. This is much better than MS Word:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Tx in the image really bolder that the R?

It doesn't look that way but hard to tell from a low resolution image. Certainly it is in italic so you do not want `\mathbf` either nothing at all or `\bm{Tx}` if you really need bold Tx.

You also have the `^` in the wrong place: the superscript is on the e so `e^{Tx}` not `e{^{Tx}}` (which puts the superscript on an empty base to the right of the e).

so

```
R^{e^{Tx}}
```

or with `bm` package

```
R^{e^{\bm{Tx}}}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I misplace *^*. It worked.